# Best way to learn objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c, flappy-bird-clone

**My aim:**

My ultimate aim is to make an iPhone game. I'm talking about something like Flappy Bird, nothing incredibly complex, but simple, addictive games.

**About Me:**

I'm 24 and have a little Python experience, but I understand that knowing a bit of Python is useless as far as Objective-C is concerned. What's the best way to learn Objective-C? Should I learn C first?

Is 24 far too late to get into this? Or is it still possible? What books should I buy? I've looked at some of the Big Nerd Ranch books and thought they were rubbish - completely over-rated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you noticed, this kind of questions is not suitable for SO. However, my advice is to learn some C, then jumping to the Apple's Objective-C guide, which is very well written. Don't make the mistake of starting writing apps and following tutorials, before you have a minimum grasp on the language.

Comment: Yeah I noticed :) Thakns Gabriele I will try and do that. I'll look for a book on C and learn some of that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn the basics of C... then pick up one of the many online tutorials and work on them until you think you know what you are doing... Python experience isn't worthless, Objective-C and Python are both OOP and both Duck-Typed... so the high level brush strokes of Python and Objective-C may be similar in some situations.